# Fill cells between specific values

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first question on here, so I hope this is ok. I have an Excel 2007 spreadsheet with many rows set up like this:

```
000000111010011001100000000000000000  
000000000000001111101101000000000000  
000000000000000000000000001010000000
```

All rows have the same length (192 cells). In each row, I need to fill all the zeros that occur between the first and last '1' with a '1' to get:

```
000000111111111111100000000000000000  
000000000000001111111111000000000000  
000000000000000000000000001110000000
```

I have tried searching on here, but cannot find a similar question. Hoping this is possible through VBA (which I am new to).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) It's kind of very simple. Try this. Loop through the rows and check for the first instance and last instance of `1` and then identify the range. Once that is done, simple fill all the values in that range with `1`. Give it a try and if you are stuck, post the code that you tried and we will take it from there?

Comment: What Siddharth sais seems to be the most feasible. In order to make the looping faster, transpose the range to an array and get on with it. Then dump the processed array back to the range. Also is it possible for you to show the print screen of your sheet? So others may get a better picture of what you are asking..

Answer (score 0):

Its simple you need some reading about vba - excel .. try to so your work .. Here is the code.I assumes you have the data in A column .

**Tested**

```
Dim lrow As Integer
Dim erange As Range
Dim reslut As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim str As String

Sub TESTING()
With ActiveSheet
lrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each erange In .Range("A1:A" & lrow)
result = returnvalue1(erange.Text, StrReverse(erange.Value))
erange.Offset(0, 1).Value = Replace(result, "0", "1")
Next erange
End With
End Sub

Function returnvalue1(ByVal val1 As String, ByVal val2 As String) As String
i = InStr(val1, 1)
Debug.Print i
j = InStr(val2, 1) - 1
Debug.Print j
j = Len(val1) - j
Debug.Print j
str = Mid(val1, i, (j - i) + 1)
returnvalue1 = str
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I am totally new to VBA and struggling here. My data is not all in column A but in a range:("A1:GC1272") how would I need to change the above code to reflect this?

Comment: Whr do u want the changes .. at the same range ?